# Android Studio Migrate Project

Tags: android, git, intellij-idea

I created a test project inside of `Android Studio` and then I used following: `VCS` -> `Enable Version Control Integration` -> `Git` -> `Ok`, then via `Project` -> `Android` -> `app`, I selected `Git` -> `Add` & `Commit Directory`.

And on another computer with `Android Studio` installed, I did following: `Check out project from Version Control` -> `Git` -> (I modified URL) `Git Repository URL` -> `Clone`, `Android Studio` asked me a lot of questions...

yet, project isn't same as on my original computer...

What am I doing wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Test]$ git status | grep -A11 Untracked
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   .idea/
#   Test.iml
#   build.gradle
#   gradle.properties
#   gradle/
#   gradlew
#   gradlew.bat
#   settings.gradle
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Test]$ cat .gitignore 
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Test]$
```

Comment: does it have build.gradle file?

Comment: @youngjae - on original computer, `build.gradle` is part of `Untracked files`, does it have to be included into VCS?

Comment: // yes. it should be. definitely. it has all dependencies and part of manifest information in order to compile the app successfully.

Comment: @youngjae what about `settings.gradle`? which other files needs to be included as well?

Comment: include it also even though it is empty content. It is better to include all files **except** things under the `.idea` folder. the `.idea` folder contains AndroidStudio specific values.

Comment: @youngjae my `settings.gradle` isn't empty, it has one line `include ':app'`.

Comment: yes. it is good to be included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79146/discussion-between-alexus-and-youngjae).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*.gradle` files are required in order to build the app project successfully. In other words, these files should be included in the VCS.

- `build.gradle` contains part of manifest and list of library dependencies.
- `settings.gradle` contains depended projects. Some projects provide entire source code.

The simplest choice is to include all files in the project folder to VCS **except** files under `.idea` folder. The `.idea` folder has IDE(Android Studio) specific files. For reference, the name *idea* is come from original program [IntellJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

If you do not want to give permission to change apk file by others, it is better to **exclude** keystore file.

**Upon your editted question, I appended descriptions accordingly as below.**

- .gradle : `.gradle` folder has gradle execution files.
- /local.properties : the keystore file location or computer-depended information like JDK path are described in here.
- /.idea/workspace.xml : it has your IDE panel location or trivial IDE settings.
- /.idea/libraries : it is automatically created/regenerated when you clean and build the project. The jar files of dependencies listed in `build.gradle` are downloaded and stored in here.
- .DS_Store : Macintosh OSX specific folder description file.
- /build : build results.
- /captures : This is not a common thing. It might be your project specific folder.